# Add "Featured Image" box in my plugin post page

Tags: plugins, images, post-thumbnails

I'm creating an Wordpress plugin where I'll have a fully customized custom post form. How can I add "Featured Image" box in my form?

For example, `wp_editor()` function shows TinyMCE editor. Is there any function to show featured image box?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add that featured image metabox you've circled to your custom post type by doing:

```
register_post_type( 'yourCPTslug', [
    //...
    'supports' => ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'] // note: thumbnail
] );


add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function () {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' , ['yourCPTslug'] );
});
```

As for a single function calling it in a position where you want it - I'm fairly certain no.